# Improving performance on a large Doctrine query

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

In Symfony3, I'm using Doctrine's QueryBuilder to iterate up to 500k rows from my 35 million row table:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->where('l.foo = :foo')
            ->setParameter('foo', $foo)
            ->getQuery();

$results = $query->iterate();

foreach ($results as $result) {
   $em->clear();
   // My logic using $result[0]
}
```

The memory usage of this often approaches 512mb, before I even begin to iterate. Is there any further way I can optimise this? Am I correct in reading that hydration is turned off when iterating a query?

Comment: Is the memory constant, or grows?

Comment: The memory grows from 20mb to ~500mb when running `$results = $query->iterate();`. Then dies down again when I begin to `$em->clear();`.

Comment: Are you using php 7?

Comment: Nope, I'm on PHP 5.5.

Comment: If you can, switch to 7,a lot more memory efficent

Comment: Hey @Jonathan, using plain SQL to iterate over the dataset a option? 

In my experience with Doctrine for large datasets I realized that it was not a good choice. Entity managers has lots of memory leaks that accumulates at each interaction, even if you flush or clear. 

In Doctrine, for processing hundreds of thousands of records was too painful. And more and more slow. Crashes after hours processing...

In most of cases the final solution was PDO + plain SQL :(

Answer (score 14):

I had great results with [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php). Perhaps processing results in a separate method helps PHP to cleanup unused objects. I'm not sure what you're doing to process your records, and cannot guarantee you'll get the same results, but in my case memory consumption remained constant through whole script execution:

```php
public function getMyResults($foo)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->where('l.foo = :foo')
        ->setParameter('foo', $foo)
        ->getQuery();

    foreach ($query->iterate() as $result) {
        yield $result[0]

        $em->clear();
    }
}

public function processMyResults($foo)
{
    foreach ($this->getMyResults($foo) as $result) {
    }
}
```

If this doesn't help, consider making a query with [DBAL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) (both with the `fetch()` method to avoid fetching all records at once). Doctrine's iterator might leak memory (PDO's resultset shouldn't).

Doctrine will solve 80% of your problems. The remaining 20% is better approached without it.

> Am I correct in reading that hydration is turned off when iterating a query?

No, unless you change the hydration mode. You can do it by passing [a second argument to the `iterate()` method](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/276a22fb6fe6659717be12531766e0abf48e7fbb/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php#L628).

Answer (score 0):

Example from  [Doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results)

```
$batchSize = 20;
$i = 1;
$q = $em->createQuery('select u from MyProject\Model\User u');
foreach ($q->toIterable() as $user) {
    $user->increaseCredit();
    $user->calculateNewBonuses();
    ++$i;
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush(); // Executes all updates.
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
}
$em->flush();
```